# pass Enumeration to function in c++

Tags: c++, enumeration

i am really confusing about how to pass an enum type to a function in c++.
i am googling and test all the soloutions presented but non of them solve my problem.
in the SocketInfo.h ,
i have an enum named SocketType that declared globally as :

```
    typedef enum SocketTypeEnum
{
    SOCKET_TYPE_IPSEC
} SocketType;
```

in the SocketInfo.h i have a class named SocketInfo :

```
class SocketInfo
{
public:
    SocketInfo(const char* ip,unsigned short fd,SocketType stype);
}
```

in the SocketInfo.cpp :

```
SocketInfo::SocketInfo(const char* ip, unsigned short fd,SocketType stype)
{
    //some work done here
}
```

i build this class without any error

now for test this class i create a win32 console application.in the _tmain i write this code

```
#include "SocketInfo.h"

void Test_Socket()
{
    SocketInfo* si = new SocketInfo(NULL,5060,SOCKET_TYPE_IPSEC);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Test_Socket();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

after running above code i got these errors:

**Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall SocketInfo::SocketInfo(char const *,unsigned short,enum SocketTypeEnum)" (??0SocketInfo@@QAE@PBDGW4SocketTypeEnum@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl Test_Socket(void)" (?Test_Socket@@YAXXZ)**

**Error 5   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals**

how i can solve these errors.

all codes compile on visual studio 2010 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in how you pass the `enum` as parameter, which is ok, but that you don't export symbols from your project or import them in your test project.

You need to add the `lib` file generated by the project defining `SocketInfo` to the additional dependencies of the test project.

You also need to export the class:

```
_declspec(dllexport) class SocketInfo
{
public:
    SocketInfo(const char* ip,unsigned short fd,SocketType stype);
};
```

and import it in the test project with `_declspec(dllimport)`. This duality is usually achieved through macros - look it up.